# BackgroundService with asp.net Core MVC 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Here is what i've done:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddHostedService<MyBatch>(); 
}


public class MyBatch : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stopToken)
    {
       while (!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
            Console.Writeline("test");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
       }
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- First: The web application does not respond on 5000 port when i launch "dotnet run". If i remove my batch, the 5000 port works again. (test messages are displayed on console)
- Second: I want to access to my database with Entity Framework. How can i access to my database context from this batch file ?

Thanks

Comment: `not respond on 5000 port when i launch "dotnet run". If i remove my batch, the 5000 port works again` Can not reproduce this issue, you can share screenshot of logs on the console, so that we can understand it better. Besides, you can try to create a new project and check if same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to access to my database with Entity Framework. How can i access to my database context from this batch file ?

To consume a scoped service (such as DbContext etc) from singleton  hosted service, you can create a scope then use it to resolve scoped service(s) you need from this scope, like below.

```
public class MyBatch : BackgroundService
{

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
    public MyBatch(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stopToken)
    {
        while (!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            await DoWithDb(stopToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWithDb(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        //...

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var _myDbContext =
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();



            //code logic here
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

You can also get detailed information about "consuming a scoped service in a background task" from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task